# Mouse wheel scrolling does not work in some windows under kde

Tags: mouse, kde, mouse-scroll, kde5

After a recent upgrade, my mouse does not scroll anymore in most kde windows.

I use a Logitech MX Master and the scroll events register without any problems in `xinput test`. Also scrolling works fine in gtk(?) windows (e.g. firefox, gvim, libreoffice) but not in any of the windows of native kde applications (dolphin, kmail, ...).

It's an annoying issue. I'd be grateful is somebody could point me in the right direction to debug this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the issue went away after an hour or so, without any reboot, re-login or any other active changes by myself. Looks like kubuntu is a bit flakey these days.

I'll mark it solved for the moment and will re-open it if the behaviour occurs again.